# Function to swap text color has to be clicked twice to work

Tags: javascript, php

I know why this is happening. I just don't know how to fix it. I am reading the text color from a database field. It sets the color of the text to whatever is in the database (either red or green). I have a button that changes this with a function call. the first time the button is pressed it by default changes the text to red (even if it is already red). I am sure this is because the style.color value is not set but I am not sure how to set it since it must be whatever is in the database. How can I solve this? Here is the PHP form that builds the file:

```
echo '<form name="form1" action="save_special_announcement.php" method="post">',
 '<h3><font color="',$row['txtColor'],'" id="currentColor">Current color of announcement&nbsp;</font><input type="button" onclick="colorRed(\'currentColor\')" value="Change" ></h3>',
 '<input type=hidden id="txtColor" name="txtColor">',
```

I am using the hidden txtColor to send to the submit page. Here is the function:

```
function colorRed(input) { // Change text to red
if(document.getElementById(input).style.color != 'red') {   
       document.getElementById(input).style.color = 'red';
       document.getElementById('txtColor').value ='red'; }
else { document.getElementById(input).style.color = 'green';
       document.getElementById('txtColor').value ='green';}
};
```

I hope I explained this as well as I could. Thank you for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't use the  tag. I would remove it and use `style="color:'.$row['txtColor'].'"'` instead.
2. Because you used the font-tag instead of css and then changed the color via style.color which changes css everything is mixed up.